# Does C# support collections of refs?

Tags: c#, collections, ref

I'm learning about C# and had a question about its capabilities. I was looking to create a list of ref tuples.

Example attempt using ints to keep it simple:

```cs
// will not compile -- just to illustrate what I want to achieve
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
List<ref int> ints = new(){ ref a, ref b, ref c };
ints[1] = 42;
Console.WriteLine(b); // should print 42
```

Comment: No, C# does not. That's it, that's the answer. There might be other options, but it's impossible to know which would be appropriate without knowing what your use case is.

Comment: You can't because you can't store `ref` in an object. You might be able to hack something using `stackalloc` and `Span`

Comment: You could in theory just store it in a `stackallock nint` span, which is safe as it cannot leak out the stack, and the references you are using are stack variables, which never move while they are live. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wbd7L0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is really to do that.

You cannot create a list of references. Each time you add an item to a list, it makes a copy of the value being added. For value types, like `int`, this means that the actual value is copied. Therefore, when you modify the original variable, the value in the list will not change because it is a copy.

However, you can use tuples as an alternative approach to achieve a similar result. Tuples in C# 7.0 allow you to store multiple fields that can be used to hold a collection of items of possibly different types. Here's an example of how you can create a list of tuples:

```
var tupleList = new List<(int Index, string Name)>
{
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b"),
    (3, "c")
};
```

You can then access the values in the tuple using their names:

```
var firstItem = tupleList[0];
Console.WriteLine($"{firstItem.Index}, {firstItem.Name}"); // Output: 1, a
```

You can also use a custom class or a struct if you need more complex data structures:

```
public class IntRef
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

var a = new IntRef { Value = 1 };
var b = new IntRef { Value = 2 };
var c = new IntRef { Value = 3 };

var list = new List<IntRef> { a, b, c };
list[1].Value = 42;

Console.WriteLine(b.Value); // Prints 42
```

Since `IntRef` is a reference type, changes to the objects in the list will be reflected in the original variables and vice versa.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid creating a new class, you could use a `List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>` or a `Dictionary<int, int>` if each value is unique

Comment: Instead of writing the custom `IntRef`, you could just use the built-in [`StrongBox<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.strongbox-1).